# Objective C interface declaration

Tags: macos, object

i'm trying a simple academic program where an interface is declared as:

```
#import <objc/Object.h>
@interface Saludador:Object{
char* saludo;
}
- init;
- (void)setSaludo:(char*)unSaludo;
- (void)setSaludo:(char*)unSaludo y:(char*)unaColetilla;
- (void)saluda;
@end
```

When I try to compile the .m file i get the error:
error: cannot find interface declaration for 'Object', superclass of 'Saludador'

I really don't know why, i'm compiling on the terminal window in a mac OSX 10.9.

thanks for the help

Comment: What's Object? Did you mean NSObject? objec/Object is correctly integrated?

Comment: import foundation or cocoa and use NSObject, you do not want to be starting at the level of Object, that is just runtime stuff

Comment: you should use Xcode and start with a default project, then you get to look at a working version, also you can read the build log and see what kind of compiler options are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` is the `OBJC_ROOT_CLASS` for ObjC 1.0, for ObjC 2.0 use `NSObject` and `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`. You'll also have to add the `-framework Foundation` as a compiler flag if you are compiling using clang or gcc on the command line.
See the header file `Object.h`:

```
#if __OBJC__  &&  !__OBJC2__

__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_NA)
OBJC_ROOT_CLASS
@interface Object
```

Note the `#if __OBJC__  &&  !__OBJC2__`.

**EDIT:** 
I actually managed to find that: `When writing code that is based upon the Foundation framework, that root class is typically NSObject` in an old document... The `OBJC_ROOT_CLASS` got me confused, so even if you're using ObjC 1.0 it's still `NSObject`.

Comment: NSObject is always the class that you specify for the root class. anything above that is just an implementation detail.

Comment: There isn't one `OBJC_ROOT_CLASS`. Both Object and NSObject are root classes. So is NSProxy.

Comment: See this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/RootClass.html